# Exp:resso store shipping plugin doesn't show up

Tags: expresso-store, plugin, shipping

I don't see the option to add the standard USPS, UPS and FedEx Shipping plugins when I add a new method.
[image]

The extension is enabled and the settings already in place. But {field:shipping_method} produces an empty drop-down on my checkout template

[image]

Comment: I'm also experiencing same thing here. I have the extension enabled, and using the {field:shipping_method} as explained here: https://exp-resso.com/docs/shipping_usps.html but still on the checkout tempalte the shipping method drop-down is empty. Any help please. William

Comment: William have you clicked on settings and entered your USPS information in the extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to goto Add-ons > Extbesions and enable the extension. The docs are a bit out of date at the moment but should be fixed soon.

The page from your screenshot is for the Default Shipping Module in Store v2. The new shipping structure will only show avilable methods based upon your shipping destinations and the customers address.

Comment: The 'Store' extension seems to be enabled unless there should be another extension name that should be enabled as well?

Comment: You need to add the fedex, ups, and usps add-ons to your third-party folder before you can enable them. They can be found at https://exp-resso.com/purchase

Comment: Sorry--I'm not a developer, this is all new to me. I'm using Stripe in conjuction with Exp:resso. Is Stripe only for handling payments and not shipping?

Comment: Hi Mike, yes. Stripe is just a payment gateway and isn't involved in the shipping process. What shipping extension are you trying to work with?

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue, Uninstalling, removing the settings in the extension table and reinstalling resolved the issue.